# How to create two commands with the same name but different number of parameters

Tags: macros

I want to define a command with the same name, but a different number of parameters.

I'm considering something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\quelle}[1]{\textit{(Quelle: \url{#1})})}
\newcommand{\quelle}[2]{\textit{(Quelle: \url{#1} Absatz: #2)})}

\begin{document}

    Test: \quelle{www.wikipedia.de}
    Test: \quelle{www.wikipedia.de, sometext}


\end{document}
```

If I try to compile this, I get the following result:

```
Command \quelle already defined. ...2]{\textit{(Quelle: \url{#1} Absatz: #2)})}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Traditional LaTeX does not allow macros with the same name having a different mandatory number of arguments. You can always define a macro having a certain number of arguments, but you have to check whether they are empty (i.e. not specified). With `expl3` you could use `\cs_new:Nn `\foo_bar:nn` or `\cs_new:Nn \foo_bar:nnnn` for example, but those macros are not meant for user space

Answer (score 6):

The only change from the requested syntax is to use a `!` as the separator between the http reference and "sometext", as I figured a comma `,` was much more likely to appear as part of "sometext:.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,listofitems}
\newcommand{\quelle}[1]{%
  \setsepchar{!}%
  \readlist\qarg{#1}%
  (\textit{Quelle: \url{\qarg[1]}}%
  \ifnum\listlen\qarg[]>1\relax\textit{ Absatz: \qarg[2]}\fi%
  )%
}
\begin{document}
    Test: \quelle{www.wikipedia.de}
    Test: \quelle{www.wikipedia.de! sometext}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I suggest an optional argument at the end, for example, with `xparse` and `\NewDocumentCommand`.

If the optional argument is not given, `\quelle` works like the intended one-argument version, if it is given `Absatz #2` is printed in addition.

The check, whether it has been specified can be done with `\IfValueT{#2}{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\newcommand{\quelle}[1]{\textit{(Quelle: \url{#1})})}
\NewDocumentCommand{\quelle}{m+o}{\textit{(Quelle: \url{#1}\IfValueT{#2}{Absatz: #2)}}}

\begin{document}

    Test: \quelle{www.wikipedia.de}

    Test: \quelle{www.wikipedia.de}[sometext]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd prefer a syntax with a leading optional argument, that's more in line with common LaTeX conventions.

Anyway, you can have your preferred syntax by defining *a single* `\quelle` command: TeX cannot have two meanings for the same command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\quelle}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m }{%
  \makequelle#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makequelle}{mm}{%
  \textit{%
    (Quelle: \url{#1}%
    \IfValueT{#2}{ Absatz: #2})%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Test: \quelle{www.wikipedia.de}

Test: \quelle{www.wikipedia.de, sometext}

\end{document}
```

The argument is split at the first comma, if present, and passed as a pair of arguments to `\makequelle`. If no comma is present, the second argument will make the test `\IfValueT` false, so nothing will be printed.

[image]

The same output with a more common syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\quelle}{om}{%
  \textit{%
    (Quelle: \url{#2}%
    \IfValueT{#1}{ Absatz: #1})%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Test: \quelle{www.wikipedia.de}

Test: \quelle[sometext]{www.wikipedia.de}          

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it my imagination, or is TeX inserting customary space after your periods in the website name?  Of course, the same applies to my own answer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That's a fault of `hyperref` or `url`, as far as I can see. Using `\textit{\url{example.org}}` will show a space after the period.

Answer (score 3):

The following code delivers what you're after using the following setup:

1. Use `\quelleattributes{<list>}` to define the prefixes/attribute names in a comma-separate `<list>` you'll be supplying (`Quelle`, `Absatz`, ...).
2. Using [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox), we process the list sequentially, setting the attribute name, followed by the attribute. A text-comparison is done with each attribute name to see whether it matches `Quelle`. *Only* those are set using `\url`, while the others are set as-is.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{quellecnt}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\quelleattributes}[1]{%
  \setcounter{quellecnt}{0}% Restart counter
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{% How to update each item
    \stepcounter{quellecnt}% Step counter
    \@namedef{quelle@\thequellecnt}{##1}% Define \quelle@<num> to attribute
  }%
  \docsvlist{#1}% Process list
}

\newcommand{\quelle}[1]{%
  \setcounter{quellecnt}{0}% Restart counter
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{quellecnt}% Step counter
    \let\quelleformat\relax% Default formatting of attribute
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@nameuse{quelle@\thequellecnt}}{Quelle}=0
      \def\quelleformat{\url}% Attribute should be a \url
    \fi
    \@nameuse{quelle@\thequellecnt}: \quelleformat{##1} % Set attribute
  }
  (\textit{%
    \docsvlist{#1}\unskip% Process list
  })%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\quelleattributes{%
  Quelle,
  Absatz%
}

Test: \quelle{www.wikipedia.de}

Test: \quelle{www.wikipedia.de, sometext}

\end{document}
```